# Extruding a bone error

Tags: rigging, bones

[image: Extruding a bone error]

I started to extrude a bone for the other arm but this happened.  What's going on with it?

**[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qdHlLcEVQOTV4cHM/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: I've never seen that before... in the future, try using x-mirror axis

Comment: How do I find x-mirror while still able to move the arms independently.

Comment: the arms will move independently in pose mode, but while creating it in edit mode, it's helpful to have perfect symmetry. x-mirror is under "options" while in edit mode.

Comment: It didn't do it.  What did I miss?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qdHlLcEVQOTV4cHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Works for me, you could also try to use rigify (an addon that you need to enable in the user preferences) to add a full rig. Expect 2hrs of tutorial watching.

Comment: Ok, still won't do X-Axis Mirror...Why?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qcFJmeFlON2I2b0k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You have Skeleton Sketching enabled.
Disable this option and use <kbd>E</kbd> button to extrude the bone or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> while the torso bone is selected.

[image]

To make the bone symmetrical on the mirrored side, after you extrude the bone enable **Forked** in Extrude Operator panel while you have X-Axis Mirror enabled

[image]

Comment: Ok, still won't do X-Axis Mirror...Why? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qcFJmeFlON2I2b0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ChristopherMonday I updated the answer.

Comment: That helped.  After I get akk the bones set do I reparent the mesh to the skeleton?   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qa0ZmaURsanBJVjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How's this look? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwnCnOOEcD5qOHRSbVVqQ0lOdk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does X-Axis Mirror work on a mesh?

Comment: For those who don't know, the X-Mirror option is part of the Options panel located at the right side of the toolbar, with [an icon like a butterfly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri1in.png) (at least for version 3.1).